# pivot returning blank instead of 0 google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet where I have an importrange and vlookup to another file where its looking up to a pivot table. Some data is blank in the pivot table and when I lookup in the formula, I have a result of blank even though I have set it to return to 0 by iferror.

Here's my formula:

=iferror(VLOOKUP(A5,importrange("12PaJfEC7Q7gOcCx2zlMHG3YybQuk1TSsNjZDw26qFRg","Converted Pivot!A:E"),3,false),0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,ifna(vlookup(A5,importrange("12PaJfEC7Q7gOcCx2zlMHG3YybQuk1TSsNjZDw26qFRg","Converted Pivot!A:E"),3,),"no_match_found"),
       if(Σ="",0,Σ))
```

- `blank_value` will now be shown as `0` & a non-match output error will be prompted with `no_match_found`